# How can I DetectFaces in Amazon Rekognition AWS with Android Studio?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, android-studio, amazon-rekognition

I have tried so many way but i can't succeed. I haven't found any source code examples for Android(about rekognition)

there's a source code in JAVA in the Developer Guide but i cannot implement that even though I tried TT

I try to detect faces by sending an image file from an external storage(from the emulator)
I don't know what i did wrong(I'm not good at coding)
Here is my code

```
AmazonRekognitionClient amazonRekognitionClient;
Image getAmazonRekognitionImage;
DetectFacesRequest detectFaceRequest;
DetectFacesResult detectFaceResult;
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"sungyeol.jpg.jpg");

public void test_00(View view) {
 ByteBuffer imageBytes;
 try{
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath().toString());
        imageBytes = ByteBuffer.wrap(IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream));
        Log.e("InputStream: ",""+inputStream);
        Log.e("imageBytes: ","");
        getAmazonRekognitionImage.withBytes(imageBytes);

        // Initialize the Amazon Cognito credentials provider
        CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                getApplicationContext(),
                "us-east-2:.......", // Identity Pool ID
                Regions.US_EAST_2 // Region
        );

        //I want "ALL" attributes
        amazonRekognitionClient = new AmazonRekognitionClient(credentialsProvider);

        detectFaceRequest = new DetectFacesRequest()
                .withAttributes(Attribute.ALL.toString())
                .withImage(getAmazonRekognitionImage);

        detectFaceResult = amazonRekognitionClient.detectFaces(detectFaceRequest);
        detectFaceResult.getFaceDetails();

    }
 catch(Exception ex){
   Log.e("Error on something:","Message:"+ex.getMessage());
 }
```

and here is my errors

```
02-04 09:30:07.268 29405-29405/? E/InputStream:: java.io.FileInputStream@a9b23e7
02-04 09:30:07.271 29405-29405/? E/Error on something:: Message:Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.amazonaws.services.rekognition.model.Image com.amazonaws.services.rekognition.model.Image.withBytes(java.nio.ByteBuffer)' on a null object reference
```

what is a null object reference?
i try to change the file path but he said no such file ... and when I change to this path, there's errors above.
by the way I've already asked a user for a permission to access a folder from Emulator in Android

please help me
PS. sorry for my bad English

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now I am ok with the issues. I have been through many many things <3 <3 <3.
Thank you

I'm Thai and I had to try harder to find the solutions because there's lack of information in the particular language. Here are my solutions.

My solutions are:

0.There is an endpoint for setting for the Rekognition-->
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#rekognition_region

1.On a "null object reference issue" I found that I have to create a new object first such as "Image image = new Image();" <-- The "new" command creates an object instance in that class

2.After the above error, there are more errors (Errors on NetworkOnMainThreadException), so I tried everything until I found this page --> 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/getting-credentials.html the page said that ...

[image]

Consequently, I looked up for more information about the AsyncTask and after that I created an AsyncTask class and then I move all my code about the initialize, the request, the response to the AsyncTask class. ตอนรันตอนท้ายๆน้ำตาจิไหล my code worked... TT and by the conclusion the sungyeol.jpg.jpg file worked

for example

```
private void testTask(){
  .... all code in the main thread particularly on the requests and responses
  from the services
 //print the response or the result
 //Log.e() makes the message in the android monitor red like an error
 Log.e("Response:", [responseparameter.toString()]);

}

//create the inherited class from the AsyncTask Class
//(you can create within your activity class)
class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{
    @Override 
    public String doInBackground(String ... input){
        testTask(); // call the testTask() method that i have created
        return null; // this override method must return String
    }

} 

//I've created a button for running the task
public void buttonTask(View view){
    AsyncTaskRunner runner = new AsyncTaskRunner();
    runner.execute();

}
```

for more information about the AsyncTask:

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html#AsyncTask

http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/01/why-and-how-to-use-asynctask.html#.WJdkqVOLTIU

I hope these help :)

Comment: It will be helpful if you can you post your solution, I'm in same situation.

Comment: I have edited my post for more information, I hope these can help you.

Comment: @ShivarajPatil पाटील, सोल्युशन द्या कि आम्हाला पण